# 画像をオブジェクトとして扱うには？

Tags: unity3d

初めて利用させていただきます。
unity初心者です。画像をSceneビューに表示させたいと思い、
<方法>画像をprojectビューにドラッグアンドドロップ→inspectorビューでtextureタイプをspriteにしてApplyという方法でしていました。
しかし、Rayを使ってオブジェクトがあるかどうかの判定をしようとしたところ、その画像は反応しませんでした。unityのデフォルトで用意されている3Dオブジェクトは反応しました。
<方法>のやり方だと画像はオブジェクトという扱いになっていないのでしょうか？
unityについての勉強はまだ日が浅く知識が全くありません。的外れな質問かと思いますがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

私も初心者なので他の手があるかもしれませんが、
Addcomponent>physics>colliderを追加すれば、衝突判定等を設定できるかと思います。